# Does Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader (ODP.Net) implements IDataReader interface?

Tags: .net, asp.net, odp.net

I'm new in ODP.Net and trying to implement it to our existing system. Currently, we are using OLEDB and using IDataReader interface to read a record from DataReader. However, when we  use ODP.Net using the same code logic, no records selected. So, my question is, does Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader (ODP.Net) implements IDataReader interface? If i try read the record using OracleDataReader without using IDataReader the record selected.

I'm using ODP.Net 10.1.0.4,
Oracle Client 10g,
ASP.Net

Edit:

```
string lstSelect = fstSelect + pstWhereClause;

IDbConnection lidcConn = fobCreateCon.CreateConnection();
lidcConn.ConnectionString = fstConStr;

IDbCommand lidcComm = fobCreateCon.CreateCommand();
lidcComm.Connection = lidcConn;
lidcComm.CommandText = lstSelect;

if (palParams != null)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < palParams.Length; i++)
 {
  IDbDataParameter lidpParam = fobCreateCon.CreateParameter(
   fstParameterPrefix + "PARA" + i.ToString(), palParams[i]);
  lidcComm.Parameters.Add(lidpParam);
 }
}

IDataReader lidrReader = null;
try
{
 lidcConn.Open();
 lidrReader = lidcComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
 bool lboReturn = lidrReader.Read();
 if (lboReturn)
 {
  fobEmployee.AR_Grace = lidrReader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : lidrReader.GetDecimal(0);
  fobEmployee.Card_Issued = lidrReader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : lidrReader.GetString(1); 
 }
 lidrReader.Close();
 return lboReturn;
}
finally
{
 if (lidrReader != null)
 {
  if (!lidrReader.IsClosed)
   lidrReader.Close();
  lidrReader.Dispose();
 }

 if (lidcConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
  lidcConn.Close();
 lidcConn.Dispose();
 lidcComm.Dispose();
}
```

Above is the code we using right now. It works perfectly with OLEDB, SQLClient. Somehow no record return when using this code with ODP.Net.

We manage to select the record when change to this

```
OracleDataReader lidrReader = null;
try
{
 lidcConn.Open();
 lidrReader = (OracleDataReader)lidcComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
 if (lidrReader.HasRow)
 {
  lidrReader.Read();
  fobEmployee.AR_Grace = lidrReader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : lidrReader.GetDecimal(0);
  fobEmployee.Card_Issued = lidrReader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : lidrReader.GetString(1); 
 }
 lidrReader.Close();
}
```

We impossible to change it to the above code cause it will involve more than 300 data file classes and we want this code working for other databases. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about `System.Data.IDataReader`, the answer is yes. In fact, `OracleDataReader` inherits from the abstract class `System.Data.Common.DbDataReader` which in turn inherits from the `System.Data.IDataReader`.

In other words, Oracle plays nice with the ADO.NET and should work more or less exactly like the other ADO.NET providers.

I have not tried with the versions prior to 10.2.x though, but I doubt things have changed significantly. I have had no problems with the `OracleDataReader`.